# 'filter' object has no attribute 'append' on evaluate a model

Tags: python, coreml, turi-create, mlmodel

I am trying to make an MLModel for use it on my app and I do it with python, since I wanna get confusion_matrix with evalute() func

here is my python code:

```py
import turicreate as tc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

train_data = tc.image_analysis.load_images("snacks/train", with_path=True)

test_data = tc.image_analysis.load_images("snacks/test", with_path=True)

model = tc.image_classifier.create(train_data, target="label", 
                                   model="squeezenet_v1.1",
                                   verbose=True, max_iterations=100)

metrics = model.evaluate(test_data) #Here is my Error
```

I tested all of them before and they work well , just when I run  `model.evaluate(test_data)` I got error

and My error is :

```
AttributeError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-56e8ce3f107f> in <module>
----> 1 model.evaluate(test_data)

~/anaconda3/envs/turienv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/turicreate/toolkits/image_classifier/image_classifier.py in evaluate(self, dataset, metric, verbose, batch_size)
    798         vectors = map(lambda l: {'name': l, 'pos':list(sf_conf_mat[sf_conf_mat['target_label']==l].sort('predicted_label')['norm_prob'])},
    799                     labels)
--> 800         evaluation_result['sorted_labels'] = hclusterSort(vectors, l2Dist)[0]['name'].split("|")
    801 
    802         # Get recall and precision per label

~/anaconda3/envs/turienv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/turicreate/toolkits/image_classifier/image_classifier.py in hclusterSort(vectors, dist_fn)
    750                         for vj in new_vec['members']:
    751                             total += dist_fn(vi, vj)
--> 752                     distances.append({'from': v, 'to': new_vec, 'dist': total/len(v.get('members', [v]))/len(new_vec['members'])})
    753 
    754                 vecs.append(new_vec)

AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I ran it on macosx highSierra (10.13.6)(cause my macbook is 2011 and I can't update it to 10.14) , python 3.6 (with conda) and I Installed turicreate via pip.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/1866

Comment: This issue came up on the [forums for the book](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/chapter-4-page-144/) as well. Try installing version 5.4 of turicreate: `pip install -U turicreate==5.4`

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans it makes a new error ‘map’ object is not subscriptable

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks I checked it , but it says i should stay for version 5.6

Comment: Try version `5.0` or `5.1`, I think that's what I used when writing the book.

Comment: Yes It worked on 5.1@MatthijsHollemans thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it's a bug on turecreate 5.5 with python 3.6 ([see this link](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/1866#issuecomment-491943730)) but when you try downgrade turicreate version to 5.4, it appears a new error that says : `‘map’ object is not subscriptable`

it works well on version 5.1, so if you got this error , you should downgrade turicreate version to 5.1 and it works
(thanks @MatthijsHollemans for helping me)

**it solved on version 5.5.1**

**Note**

Turi's group try to solve it on the next version ( you can see this card [Error Image_Classifier](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/projects/3#card-21452055) )